# Node - best use cases for defining a function using let in regards to promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

in regards to Promises in node, what are the main differences between using `let` (or var and const) to define a function as opposed to creating a function on its own?

```js
let balanceFunc = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    exchange.balance((error, balances) => {
        if (error) reject(error); else resolve(balances);
    });

});

async function test() {
    await balanceFunc.then((result) => {
        console.log(result.MSFT);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

test()
```

vs

```js
function balanceFunc() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        exchange.balance((error, balances) => {
            if (error) reject(error); else resolve(balances);
        });

    });
}


async function test() {
    await balanceFunc().then((result) => {
        console.log(result.MSFT);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

test()
```

Is the only difference between cosmetics or are there certain cases in which one would be preferable. What about if there were multiple arguments in the function?

Comment: aside: don't mix `await` and `.then()` syntaxes in the same function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case:

```
let balanceFunc = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
```

this creates the Promise and calls `exchange.balance` *as soon as the line runs*. In contrast, when you have a function wrapper around it in your second code, the Promise creation and the API call will only occur *when the function is called*.

For example, if this is intended for consumers of this module, and you did:

```
export const balanceFunc = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  // ...
```

This would result in `exchange.balance` being called *only once*, when the module is initially loaded. For APIs that return different values depending on the time at which they're called, this is almost certainly not what you want: in contrast, using the function version of `balanceFunc` will call the API anew each time the function is called.

If the API you're using needs to be requested only once, creating a single Promise instead of wrapping a function around it is just fine. (You could still wrap it in a function, of course, but you'd probably want to make sure to only call that wrapper function once)